# Create team sections (or segregated areas)

Tags: mediawiki

I'm considering using mediawiki as my company's internal knowledge base and am trying to understand how to build out effective team sections. Unfortunately, I'm not finding much information on this.

Ideally we'd have a separate knowledge base sections for devs, product, design and HR; all in the same system with the ability to cross-link. Each of these sections would be able to have it's own landing page and we could search for content specifically within that section.

It looks like using categories might work, but initially this feels clunky and I'm not sure if it provides the level of hierarchy I'm looking for. I would love to get your ideas and any links to examples that have done this well.

Thank you!

Comment: [Namespaces](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Namespaces) provide a separation of entirely different kinds of data.

Answer (score 0):

If by segregation you mean limited visibility (ie. team members generally shouldn't be able to see other members' content), then MediaWiki is probably not the right choice for you as it does not have granular read access control.

If you are simply looking for content organization, namespaces provide an ugly but easy way of partitioning (almost everything supports filtering by namespace). Categories are more elegant but not so well integrated - you can filter search results by category but you can't do it for most other things like recent changes or user contributions.